# Publishing a big raster layer via GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have a big raster layer (7GB) and I want to publish it so it can be accessible from my Geoportal using OpenLayers 4. I couldn't find a clear procedure to do that, I started by tiling the image but I don't know next steps.

```
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "BLOCKXSIZE=256" -co "BLOCKYSIZE=256" -targetDir C:\Users\Downloads\Compressed\bmpyramid C:\Users\Downloads\Compressed\img.tif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the [instructions in the manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html) on creating and using an image pyramid.

Comment: thanks for the reply I started wih that tutoriel but I don't know how it can be implemented in openlayers

Comment: it works just like any other wms layer